# difficulty while starting cqlsh shell

Tags: cassandra-2.0, cqlsh

I want to start cqlsh shell but it gives me error like

**Connection error: 
Unable to connect to any servers',
    {'127.0.0.1': error(10061,"Tried connecting to [('127.0.0.1', 9042)]. 
Last error: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it")})`**

Comment: And Cassandra is running on the local machine and listening on port 9042?

Comment: yes cassandra is running on local machine on port 9042

Comment: Do you have a local firewall?

Comment: yes my firewall is on do i need to turn it off and if yes will u please give me steps to turn off firewall

Comment: Disable it to see whether it makes a difference.

Comment: It seems [you resolved your issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36721192/cqlsh-query-for-wildcard-characters). It would be nice if you let people know how.

Answer (score 0):

For the default installation, in order to use cqlsh you must be logged in as root. You cannot simply use sudo, as that only grants root privileges if allowed; but you can use su. I hope this helps.