# Cqlsh query for wildcard characters

Tags: cassandra-2.0, cqlsh, solr-query-syntax

I want a query to perform following operation

List employees name either start or end with A

but i seen on some sites that cassandra do not support wildcard characters is it true or not

i also refered solr_query but cqlsh gives error undefined name solr_query

select * from emp where solr_query='name:A* or name:*A'; where name is coloumn

please help me out with this

Comment: [Solr search integration](https://docs.datastax.com/en/datastax_enterprise/4.0/datastax_enterprise/srch/srchTOC.html) is a Datastax enterprise feature. I don't think it is available in the community edition or Cassandra.

Answer (score 0):

Full Text Search is only a feature of DataStax Enterprise. So for Apache Cassandra, you have no such facility.

Hope it helps!